# Rollup CommonJS plugin throwing error when importing Sass files in dependencies

Tags: sass, commonjs, svelte, rollup, sapper

I'm using Rollup on a Sapper project found here: https://github.com/darryl-snow/perfect-cookie

Yesterday I ran `npm update` and since then when I run `npm run dev` I get the following error:

```
✗ client
Invalid CSS after "...-features: list": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".append($available-"
✗ server
Invalid CSS after "...-features: list": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".append($available-"
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985
  throw err;
  ^
```

My rollup config:

```
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace'
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte'
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss'
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel'
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser'
import config from 'sapper/config/rollup.js'
import pkg from './package.json'

const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV
const dev = mode === 'development'
const legacy = !!process.env.SAPPER_LEGACY_BUILD

const onwarn = (warning, onwarn) =>
  (warning.code === 'CIRCULAR_DEPENDENCY' && /[/\\]@sapper[/\\]/.test(warning.message)) || onwarn(warning)
const postcssOptions = () => ({
  extensions: ['.scss', '.sass'],
  extract: false,
  minimize: true,
  use: [
    [
      'sass',
      {
        includePaths: ['./src/theme', './node_modules'],
      },
    ],
  ],
})

export default {
  client: {
    input: config.client.input(),
    output: config.client.output(),
    plugins: [
      replace({
        'process.browser': true,
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(mode),
      }),
      svelte({
        dev,
        hydratable: true,
        emitCss: true,
      }),
      resolve({
        browser: true,
        dedupe: ['svelte'],
      }),
      commonjs(),

      postcss(postcssOptions()),

      legacy &&
        babel({
          extensions: ['.js', '.mjs', '.html', '.svelte'],
          runtimeHelpers: true,
          exclude: ['node_modules/@babel/**'],
          presets: [
            [
              '@babel/preset-env',
              {
                targets: '> 0.25%, not dead',
              },
            ],
          ],
          plugins: [
            '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
            [
              '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
              {
                useESModules: true,
              },
            ],
          ],
        }),

      !dev &&
        terser({
          module: true,
        }),
    ],

    onwarn,
  },

  server: {
    input: config.server.input(),
    output: config.server.output(),
    plugins: [
      replace({
        'process.browser': false,
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(mode),
      }),
      svelte({
        generate: 'ssr',
        dev,
      }),
      resolve({
        dedupe: ['svelte'],
      }),
      commonjs(),

      postcss(postcssOptions()),
    ],
    external: Object.keys(pkg.dependencies).concat(
      require('module').builtinModules || Object.keys(process.binding('natives'))
    ),

    onwarn,
  },

  serviceworker: {
    input: config.serviceworker.input(),
    output: config.serviceworker.output(),
    plugins: [
      resolve(),
      replace({
        'process.browser': true,
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(mode),
      }),
      commonjs(),
      !dev && terser(),
    ],

    onwarn,
  },
}
```

I've tried `rm -rf ./node_modules && npm install` but still getting the same error. It looks like commonJS is loading dependencies and finding one where it's expecting CSS but getting Sass... I'm completely new to rollup, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably consider installing the latest major version of `@rollup/plugin-commonjs`. The one you're currently using has a bug with Sapper (which I've encountered while running your repo instead of the one in the question) and it was fixed in the later versions.

After upgrading that, your project seems to start up fine.

While you're at it, upgrade the other major version upgrades, very likely that most of them will go by without errors.